# Need help finding a My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic fanfic, that has a little section about Rarity's accent

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

I read a fanfic from [Fimfiction.net](https://www.fimfiction.net/), and in a minor part, Applejack or Rainbow Dash says that Rarity's parents come from, I think a ponified version of Minnesota... and that Rarity uses her accent and changing the topic to hide her heritage from Canterlot nobles.

A key phrase used by the pony commenting, is "Don't cha know", or possibly "Don't ya know", to highlight the Minnesota accent, to, I think Twilight Sparkle, as part of a discussion on Canterlot? Or more likely families?

Perhaps Shining Armor, Twilight's brother, was also mentioned?

I think it's a story by [Estee](https://www.fimfiction.net/user/109909/Estee), it might be actually be from [FanOfMostEverything](https://www.fimfiction.net/user/1400/FanOfMostEverything)? Or maybe even some other author.

Comment: Aren't Rarity's parents shown with Minnesotan accents as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWpIYnuD-jE?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Yes, but... I don't see how that's relevant? Other than the fic in question referencing that?

Comment: Ah, I guess, as much as anything, I'm trying to figure out what I can search for that won't just turn up MLP episodes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Thanks for trying, and hopefully you succeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, when coincidentally rereading the story, [Petriculture](https://www.fimfiction.net/story/14298/petriculture)! I guess I never found it because there's no space between "don't" and "cha"?

> “I dunno [why Pinkie Pie would lie about her family]. Why do you try to hide the fact that your family’s from St. Paulomino every time you go to Canterlot?”
>
> This left Rarity predictably flustered. “What… well… I… that is… well, I never!”
>
> “Where’s St. Paulomino?” Fluttershy asked.
>
> “Oh, it’s a ways to the north of here,” Rainbow Dash replied in the accent stereotyped with the region. “Yah, you only have to talk to her parents for about a minute before it’s obvious that’s where they’re from, don’tcha know.”